# 5v input on ATmega328p running on 3.3v

Tags: atmega328, voltage-level

The ATmega328p can run on 5v but will it cause problems if it runs on 3.3 v and one input signal is 5v?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic levels can be different across differently made integrated circuits and processors.  You should not directly connect differently powered devices together.  Logic level differences (as described [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/logic-levels)) should be dealt with using logic level converting devices such as [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009).

Answer (score 0):

The voltage at any input *must* be less than V<sub>CC</sub>+0.3V unless it is restricted to only a few milliamperes (so it doesn't burn out the clamping diode). Use a proper voltage translator if it is available, otherwise use a 1kohm or greater resistor (at the cost of life expectancy for the MCU).